# How to judge a custom class whether mutable or immutable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We know `NSArray` is immutable and `NSMutableArray` is mutable,because we can judge by it's name.But how can we know a custom class whether mutable?

Comment: Do you mean by looking at its API and documentation or are you referring to some sort of check at runtime?

Comment: @rmaddy When a object is immutable,copy is shallow copy,mutableCopy is deep copy;Otherwise both copy and mutableCopy are deep copy.So I wonder this class whether mutable or not that I can know whether copy is deep copy.

Comment: No, neither `copy` or `mutableCopy` are a deep copy. When you call `copy` or `mutableCopy` on either `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, only the array is copied, not the objects in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's no special interface or API in Objective-C or OS library to do this.

You can start by checking the known types like so:

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    return YES; // mutable
}
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]]) {
    return YES; // mutable
}
... etc.
```

And for your own custom objects you can create your own custom "marker" protocol:

```
@protocol MYMutable <NSObject>
@end
```

(you apply that protocol to your own objects)

And then check your objects like so:

```
if ([obj conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MYMutable)]) {
    return YES;
}
```

This is not perfect solution, but it might cover 90% of the use cases.